# DB2 ORDER BY query slow when using sort by two fields

Tags: sql, performance, select, db2, sql-order-by

I have a DB2 table which has the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE "CONTACTS" (
  "ID" CHAR(36) NOT NULL, 
  "DELETED" SMALLINT DEFAULT 0, 
  "FIRST_NAME" VARCHAR(200), 
  "LAST_NAME" VARCHAR(200)
);

    CREATE INDEX "IDX_CONTACTS_DEL_LAST" ON "CONTACTS"
    ("DELETED"  ASC, 
     "LAST_NAME"    ASC) 
     MINPCTUSED 0 ALLOW REVERSE SCANS PAGE SPLIT SYMMETRIC COMPRESS YES;

    CREATE INDEX "IDX_CONTACT_LASTNAME" ON "CONTACTS"
    ("LAST_NAME"    ASC, 
     "DELETED"  ASC)
     MINPCTUSED 0 ALLOW REVERSE SCANS PAGE SPLIT SYMMETRIC COMPRESS YES;

    CREATE INDEX "IDX_CONT_LAST_FIRST" ON "CONTACTS"
    ("LAST_NAME"    ASC, 
     "FIRST_NAME"   ASC, 
     "DELETED"  ASC)
     MINPCTUSED 0 ALLOW REVERSE SCANS PAGE SPLIT SYMMETRIC COMPRESS YES;

    CREATE INDEX "IDX_ID_DEL" ON "CONTACTS"
    ("ID"   ASC, 
     "DELETED"  ASC)
     MINPCTUSED 0 ALLOW REVERSE SCANS PAGE SPLIT SYMMETRIC COMPRESS YES;

    CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "CONTACTSPK" ON "CONTACTS"
    ("ID"   ASC)
     MINPCTUSED 0 ALLOW REVERSE SCANS PAGE SPLIT SYMMETRIC COMPRESS YES;

    ALTER TABLE "CONTACTS" ADD CONSTRAINT "CONTACTSPK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID");
```

This query works fine (fast):

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT contacts.id, contacts.first_name, contacts.last_name 
  FROM contacts WHERE contacts.deleted=0 
ORDER BY contacts.last_name ASC) 
LIMIT 21 OPTIMIZE FOR 21 ROWS
```

However this is almost 1000 times slower on sizeable (millions of rows) database:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT contacts.id, contacts.first_name, contacts.last_name 
FROM contacts WHERE contacts.deleted=0 
ORDER BY contacts.last_name ASC, contacts.id ASC) 
LIMIT 21 OPTIMIZE FOR 21 ROWS
```

Now, I was assuming that once `last_name` is indexed and has sufficient cardinality (which it does) adding secondary sorting should not matter. However, turns out it matters a lot - it makes the query thousand times slower. My question is why is that - shouldn't DB2 just take first 21 rows from `last_name/deleted` index, which should be very fast, sort them by `ID` and then be done with it? It looks however that it does full table scan or at least something very expensive. So my question is why?

Second question is if there is a way to add secondary sorting field without causing such effect. The reason is as fields will be added to `contacts` they would have their indexes, but adding `id` to every index looks wasteful. OTOH, some fields can have a lot of records with the same `last_name` or other value, so it'd be useful to have stable order for those rows, especially when paginating. Does DB2 guarantee such order without secondary sorting?

Comment: Maybe you could start by looking at the output from `EXPLAIN` for each of the two queries?

Comment: @IanBjorhovde unfortunately while EXPLAIN shows that the slow one does not use the index, it does nothing to explain why it doesn't and how to make it to.

Answer (score 1):

The index that you want is on `contacts(deleted, lastname, id)`.  This will work on the query both with just `lastname` as the sort key and with both `lastname` and `id`.

The reason for the performance problem.  First, the fast query with just `lastname` uses the index.  The other may or may not use the index, but it has to fetch *all* the rows with the same `lastname`  Then it has to sort them by `id`.  After all, there is no reason to think that the first 21 rows in the index with the same `lastname` would all have the same `id`.

The issue may be one of two things.  The first is that one last name could have many records with the same `id`.  The second is simply that DB2 gets confused because of the presence of `id` and decides not to use the index.

Although it probably won't help the query, you should declare `id` to be a primary key if, indeed, it is one.

Comment: I've looked at the actual data and while there are some records with same last names, there are not many of them - not more than 2-3 per name. Should not cause 1000x slowdown. So it looks like for some reason DB2 just gives up on indexes for secondary sort.